# In C++, how does one use a class member that will hold any object derived from a base class?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Thanks in advance for reading and/or responding to this. I am quite new to programming.

Say I had a Player class that used an ABC type Weapon object as a member.

```
class Player
{
private:
Weapon * mainHand;  // I think this is what I want?
};
```

But I want to assign any derived class type, such as a club, or dagger. How do I assign a new object to it? As you may have guessed, I'd like the user to be able to make a run-time decision to "equip" any of multiple available objects.

Anyway, I've tried for about 2 weeks to figure it out by reading stuff on forums and I've simply failed. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: How would you assign a weapon, if it was not supposed to be derived? Can you also perhaps show your best "failed" attempt?

Comment: Maybe you can show what you tried, and explain how it failed?

Comment: Thank you two for your responses, I think I have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign `mainHand` variable to pointer to any object of type derived from `Weapon` class. Like that(just the example, not the design suggestion):

```
void equipClub()
{
    Club* someShinyClub = new Club();
    mainHand = someShinyClub;
}
```

or even directly:

```
mainHand = new Club();
```

After that all the methods the Weapon declares would be accessible from that pointer. But for specific operations from the derived classes you would need a cast.

Comment: Adding an `equipWhatever()` method for every weapon type is not extendable.

Comment: Of course it's not. I specially pointed that it's not a design suggestion.

Comment: Awesome! That helped a lot. Obviously, I'm a huge newb.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to be able to decide the weapon choice of the Player at runtime.

You are probably aware of the fact that you need derived classes from `Weapon` for that.

You simply can do the following; though I recommend you to find a more efficient way. ( `Dagger` and `Sword` classes )

```
if(player.weaponchoice == "dagger") //assuming that the player will decide the weapon choice.
{
   player.mainHand = new Dagger();
} 
else if(player.weaponchoice == "sword")
{
   player.mainHand = new Sword();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Weapon refernce can be assigned any Object that extends Weapon. 
So if club extends Weapon, you can write:

```
this->mainHand = new Club();
```

mainHand can only call public and protected methods in the Weapon class, though.

```
this->mainHand->fire();
```

If you want to call methods specific to club, you'll have to cast it but there should not be a need to do this!

```
((Club *) this->mainHand)->beatToDeath();
```

Comment: Apparantly I had no idea how to properly use -> before now. Thank you so much for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Please see below example. Please adopt as per your need.

```
class Weapon
{
public:
    virtual void fire()=0;
};

class Gun:public Weapon
{
public:
    void fire()override
    {
        std::cout<<"Gun\n";
    }
};

class Rifle:public Weapon
{
public:
    void fire()override
    {
        std::cout<<"Rifle\n";
    }
};

class Player
{
public:
    Player(Weapon* weapon):mainHand(weapon)
    {
    }
    void fire()
    {
        mainHand->fire();
    }
private:
Weapon * mainHand;  // I think this is what I want?
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Gun gun;
    Rifle rifle;
    Player p1(&gun);
    Player p2(&rifle);
    p1.fire();
    p2.fire();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Definitely gives me some new ideas.